# jQuery BBQ - "Access Denied" in IE

Tags: jquery, hash, hashchange, jquery-bbq

I'm running into issues with jQuery BBQ in IE7 and IE8 compatibility mode.

```
history_set = function( hash, history_hash )

var iframe_doc = iframe.document, //this is the line that the error reports

domain = $.fn[ str_hashchange ].domain;`
```

I get an "Access Denied" on the line marked above.

I've heard this can be caused by the iframe having a domain issue, so I set

```
document.domain = "mydomain.com";
```

but still seeing the issue.

help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for anyone else receiving this error, this is how we fixed it.

First, at the suggestion of Ben Alman, we made a one line change to the plugin. Where the iframe is appended to the window, `.contentWindow` we change to `.document`

We also needed to use the blank html file, and set the source:

```
//set iframe src file, will not work in IE7 & compat modes without
            jQuery.fn.hashchange.domain = document.domain;
            jQuery.fn.hashchange.src = 'blank.html';

            //Initialize our BBQ
                     blah blah blah
```

With those changes, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here didn't work for me, but there is an example implementation here that did:
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/document_domain/

document.domain needs to be set before jQuery is loaded, and it must match the document.domain setting in the hashchange.src file.